# Contact form block with data from the page the blocks featured on

Tags: 7, hooks, emails

So I have a content type "Real Estate." On the view for a "Real Estate" node, I want to have a contact block in the right side bar that has a feild for the node id of this specific "Real Estate" node.

An example of the feature I'm trying to make can be seen [here](http://www.apartments.com/Pennsylvania/Philadelphia/Chestnut-Hill-Village-Apartments/786240?SearchCriteria=IS-%7C6qOxQ0rgfNJ4SQ4h/kTHjMSId8Iqz8GOKXJrdaeDO3xZP7e4m3kmjC8A2toGw1oxwO9bGSt0gFueR0yDcg8sBCmf23X5NMHTl7U5n1TxyIhFmRFK894szfPW-%7Ckjl2ikFZ78qVYs2mCtFAoLq7Dcz-%7C-%7CADPasBvyCiNfOQvY015uvLlq1Jk6lxQ/smFkEgr&sid=24b3747b-d519-4c9b-9869-7bbfae0f4c2a&Hidebackresults=T)

This problem has two parts which I'm not sure how to do. The first is that I don't know how to make a block for a contact form. I know drupal has a default Contact module but I'm not sure how to turn this into a block or even if that is the best way to go (maybe WebForms module can help?) Second is that I'm not sure how to pre-load the node id into the form. I'm sure that this would require a hook of some kind but seeing as I don't know how to make the contact form block, I don't know what hook to use.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write custom theming and you want less coding, you need to create a custom page with 2 columns using panels module.

1. Install the [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and [ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) modules if you don't have.
2. Enable Chaos tools, Page manager and Panels.
3. Create a custom page at **admin/structure/pages/add** with the path "estate/%node" which will be a new mirror page of the existing path "node/%node".
4. Assign **Node: ID** context to the argument **%node**.
5. Choose two column layout.
6. Add **Existing node** to the left column. To use a NID from the URL, use **%1** in the title box.
7. For the right column, add the contact form from **Widgets**.

To get node information in the contact form, you need to write a hook [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) in your custom module using the argument NID.
You can study custom moduling [here](http://drupal.org/node/361112).
Here is the example code snippet.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 * @see http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter
 */
function yourmodule_form_contact_mail_page_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if(arg(0) == 'estate' && is_numeric(arg(1)){
        $node = node_load(arg(1));
    }

}
?>
```

You can also see how can you customize the contact form here:
http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-add-field-drupal-contact-form
http://www.isegura.es/blog/modifying-contact-form-drupal-how-add-field
http://www.pensamientosdivergentes.net/blog/modifying-contact-form-drupal-how-add-field

The drawback of this solution is you have to use the new path "estate/%node" to the node view page instead of using the default existing path "node/%node".
Any better answer is welcome.